# Conditionally use today's date or report date for the last row of each group in SQL

Tags: sql, date, amazon-redshift

I have a table with of reported transactions in Redshift/PostgreSQL where from time to time I upload a report with the invoices and their due and paid dates like this:

| invoice_Id | report_date | due_date | paid_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 08-26-2021 | 09-02-2021 | 08-25-2021 |
| A2 | 08-26-2021 | 08-29-2021 |  |
| A3 | 08-26-2021 | 09-05-2021 |  |
| A4 | 08-26-2021 | 08-30-2021 |  |
| A1 | 08-28-2021 | 09-02-2021 | 08-25-2021 |
| A2 | 08-28-2021 | 08-29-2021 |  |
| A3 | 08-28-2021 | 09-05-2021 | 08-27-2021 |
| A4 | 08-28-2021 | 08-30-2021 |  |
| A1 | 08-30-2021 | 09-02-2021 | 08-25-2021 |
| A2 | 08-30-2021 | 08-29-2021 |  |
| A3 | 08-30-2021 | 09-05-2021 | 08-27-2021 |
| A4 | 08-30-2021 | 08-30-2021 |  |

I need to calculate the status of the invoices based on paid_date, due_date and
(here is the tricky part) report_date or TODAY when the report is the last one of each invoice.

| invoice_Id | report_date | due_date | paid_date | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 08-26-2021 | 09-02-2021 | 08-25-2021 | PAID |
| A2 | 08-26-2021 | 08-29-2021 |  | PENDING |
| A3 | 08-26-2021 | 09-05-2021 |  | PENDING |
| A4 | 08-26-2021 | 08-30-2021 |  | PENDING |
| A1 | 08-28-2021 | 09-02-2021 | 08-25-2021 | PAID |
| A2 | 08-28-2021 | 08-29-2021 |  | PENDING |
| A3 | 08-28-2021 | 09-05-2021 | 08-27-2021 | PAID |
| A4 | 08-28-2021 | 08-30-2021 |  | PENDING |
| A1 | 08-30-2021 | 09-02-2021 | 08-25-2021 | PAID |
| A2 | 08-30-2021 | 08-29-2021 |  | PAST_DUE |
| A3 | 08-30-2021 | 09-05-2021 | 08-27-2021 | PAID |
| A4 | 08-30-2021 | 08-30-2021 |  | PENDING |

Assuming TODAY is 08-31-2021:

| invoice_Id | report_date | due_date | paid_date | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 08-30-2021 | 09-02-2021 | 08-25-2021 | PAID |
| A2 | 08-30-2021 | 08-29-2021 |  | PAST_DUE |
| A3 | 08-30-2021 | 09-05-2021 | 08-27-2021 | PAID |
| A4 | 08-30-2021 | 08-30-2021 |  | PAST_DUE |

As you can see:

I am trying something like:

```
SELECT report_date, due_date, paid_date,
  CASE
   WHEN paid_date IS NOT NULL THEN 'PAID'
   WHEN report_date > due_date AND paid_date is null THEN 'PAST_DUE'
   WHEN report_date <= due_date THEN 'PENDING'
  END as status
FROM reported_transaction
```

But I need to make sure that for the last row of each invoice reported transaction it uses today's date in the transaction. So instead of:

```
   ...
   WHEN report_date > due_date AND paid_date is null THEN 'PAST_DUE'
   WHEN report_date <= due_date THEN 'PENDING'
   ...
```

it uses:

```
   ...
   WHEN get_date() > due_date THEN 'PAST_DUE'
   WHEN get_date() <= due_date THEN 'PENDING'
   ...
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: @alex does the solution below works ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this ?

- First step is to create rank based on date.
- Then get the maximum rank and then compare the maximum rank per id with each rank column that we created in first CTE
- If the rank is same as of max rank then we do your current data condition else the normal conditons

```
    WITH ranked_date as (
    
    select 
    *,
    row_number() over(partition by invoice_id order by report_date) as ranked_date
    
    from [table name]
    ),
    
    max_rank as (
    select
    invoice_id,
    max(ranked_date) as max_ranked_date
    from ranked_date
    group by 1
    )
    
    select 
    ranked_date.invoice_id,
    ranked_date.ranked_date,
    CASE 
         WHEN ranked_date.ranked_date = max_rank.max_ranked_date THEN
             CASE
                 WHEN get_date() > due_date THEN 'PAST_DUE'
                 WHEN get_date() <= due_date THEN 'PENDING'
                 END
         WHEN ranked_date.ranked_date != max_rank.max_ranked_date THEN
             CASE 
                 WHEN report_date > due_date AND paid_date is null THEN 'PAST_DUE'
                 WHEN report_date <= due_date THEN 'PENDING'
             END
    ELSE 'NO CONDITION SPECIFIED' 
    END AS new_status
    
    
    FROM ranked_date
    INNER JOIN max_rank 
    ON ranked_date.invoice_id = max_rank.invoice_id
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I think this make sense, but I am still wrapping my head around ranked_date.ranked_date = max_rank.max_ranked_date vs ranked_date.ranked_date != max_rank.max_ranked_date and then null as new_status. I tried in my code and didn't work, but I think I might be missing something.

Comment: @AlexRamirez those are basically your conditions. I am using nested Case when statements. As I don't have visibility on your data there might be some syntax error but the logic is first check if the max rank = rank value this will be your last entry per invoice and so you would have a condition of get_date(). If the rank is different than maximum rank then it means it is not the last invoice entry of that invoice_id and then your conditions are without the get_date() ones

Comment: if you run the code without case statements (comment them out) and add just max_ranked_date in the last statement instead. Do you see the rankings correctly ?

Comment: @AlexRamirez i made some adjustment in case when, but i would need to know what are your results

Comment: In the end if no such condition is met then it will put 'NO CONDITION SPECIFIED'. If i am missing the conditions you can add them based on your use case

Comment: I am getting this error: `relation "max_rank" does not exist`

Comment: @AlexRamirez ajusted try again

Comment: was missing a table name

Comment: Without conditions I get this error: `invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table [table name]` and yes, I replacing [table name] with my table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236610/discussion-between-trillion-and-alex-ramirez).

Comment: i need to see what you are running, please switch to chat mode